# Android display gradient image

Tags: android

I use the below code to test gradient image.

```
myView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
if(bitmap!=null){
  myView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

The gradient image can display normal when I compile it in sdk 10-13 of android2.3-android3.1. If I compile this in the sdk 15 of android4.0, the gradient image can not display and have the clear outline.

I check on line it said that the default format is rgb565 in android 4.0. And I need to set the format `getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);` to show 24 bits image. But it still can not display.

How to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but setting  android:hardwareAccelerated="false" for your activity may help.